# Advanced Pricing data

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Is there any way to access the advanced pricing data in QuickBooks (R14)?  I have got products with quantity discounts, and I need to pull the data into Excel, either through the SQK (preferred) or at bare minimum an (excel) report.  Seems that data access wasn't considered by Intuit for this add-on, unless it's undocumented...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not accessible. No surprise, either.

Comment: Is there any documentation saying this isn't accessible, or is it just not exposed anywhere that you have found? Thanks